# Is there an alternative to PCA that produces a unique representation?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, computational-statistics, graph-theory, computer-vision

PCA produces solutions that are not unique i.e. the resulting representation could be recreated using a different set of points. This is where my problem lies. I was wondering whether anyone is aware of any other techniques that would produce unique representations when performing dimensionality reduction of some data points. There is a lemma known as Johnson-Lindenstauss Lemma that does dimensionality reduction while producing unique representations of data but it is dependent on the size of the data points. What I am looking for is a technique that would perform unique dimensionality reduction and is independent of the size of data points (similar to PCA which produces a fixed number of eigenvectors but isn't independent of data size).

Comment: You can definitely systematically choose one of the solutions since they are for all intend and purpose equivalent. For example,  you could multiply each eigen-vectors so that its largest entries (in absolute value) is positive. Then, the solutions would always be unique. Can you comment why such a hack would not be a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow this. If you have a new dataset, even if they are measures of the same variables & w/ the same N, the output from a PCA will differ.  The PC's, eigenvectors, etc. will have sampling distributions like anything else in statistics.

Comment: I'm wondering how a dimension reduction technique can be anything other than a many-to-one relationship. So different data could produce the same summary.

Comment: I agree with all three comments above (+1 to each); this question is unclear.